# Android Data Binding conditional menu?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-databinding

I'm try to set different menus based on the user's role using the data binding library.

In the fragment of code below you can see that if the user is an *educator* I would set the `activity_main_educator_drawer` otherwise the `activity_main_child_drawer`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="sc.me.twelve.viewmodels.UserViewModel" />
    </data>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@{user.getModel.getRole.equals(`educator`) ? @menu/activity_main_educator_drawer : @menu/activity_main_child_drawer}" >

            <include
                layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                bind:user="@{user}" />

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

It seems good, but I have this error:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. activity_main_educator_drawer is missing it
```

### FINALLY

The [George Mount's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42729827/4735866) is the right one, I've just added the `BindingAdapter`.

```
@BindingAdapter("app:menu")
public static void setMenu(NavigationView navigationView, int id) {
    navigationView.inflateMenu(id);
}
```

Comment: I think you have not wrap your navigationview by `<layout>` tag.

Comment: I wrote that is a _fragment of code_ and not the entire document. If you need all the code tell me.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you need to swap the `"` and the `'` -   `app:menu='@{viewModel.getModel.getRole.equals("educator") ? @menu/activity_main_educator_drawer : @menu/activity_main_child_drawer}'`

Comment: As far as I know - you can't bind "@menu" now.

Comment: @Amylinn I tried every combinations of `"`, `'` and `\``, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ekalips it could be, but I didn't find this limitation on the Android support.

Comment: @SamueleColombo I literally faced same problem month ago, and found only workaround, but no straight way

Comment: @Ekalips Probably menus are more complex than other resources. I'm going to accept your answer, however if you have links to share it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the menu resource isn't being recognized. Try this expression instead:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        ...
        app:menu="@{user.getModel.getRole.equals(`educator`) ? R.menu.activity_main_educator_drawer : R.menu.activity_main_child_drawer}" >
```

Make sure to import the R class:

```
<data>
    <import type="sc.me.twelve.R"/>
</data>
```

or whatever your package is.

I see a small strangeness in your expression. I *think* it can be simplified:

```
app:menu="@{user.model.role.equals(`educator`) ? R.menu.activity_main_educator_drawer : R.menu.activity_main_child_drawer}"
```

The "get" or "is" prefix is assumed for accessor methods.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work and shows this error: `Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:menu' with parameter type int on android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`. It is quite explanatory and I don't think that there is a workaround.

Comment: I was assuming that you had written a Binding Adapter. If not, you should write one that takes an int.